# React form inputs as SQL parameters

Tags: python, sql, reactjs, parameter-passing, teradata

Can someone help with building a front-end to pass variables through a React form to pull reports from a back-end SQL query to Teradata. Would appreciate any help and direction.

So far I've learned:

- I have a python program that I can query teradata through, but don't
  know how to pass variables via a front-end
- Node has a Teradata module, but I'm not sure how to pass variables to node from React (I'm very new to React and don't know node,
  willing to learn though)
- I know enough about react to build the front-end form, inputs, props, etc.
- I've done a lot of research and realize this is probably an outdated
  request, so if there is an easier way to do it, I'm all for it

What I'd like to build:

- My team doesn't know SQL so I would like a simple interface for a repeatable query where they can
  change basic parameters via an input form
- A front-end webapp that they can pass params like dates, include/exclude checkboxes,
  etc. to pass to the SQL query, but doesn't need to complex
- I've been learning React so would prefer to use that but also open to others

Comment: They would've downvoted because Stack Overflow is for help with specific problems, not general "how do I build something like this" type questions. Maybe the software engineering stack exchange might be a more suitable place: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try to re-write the question for exactly what I need.